# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module. I'm using typescript and discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js, es6-modules

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this pesky bug:
`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`
I'm using discord.js and typescript to create a discord bot. I'm currently creating my own command handler by dynamically importing all files in a `commands` dir. However, whenever I import such file
Code at question:

```
Promise.all((await getCommands("private")).map(async absPath => {
            return { name : basename(absPath), mod:  ( await import(absPath)).mod as fdjsMod  }
         })).then( modArr => {
             for ( const { name, mod } of modArr) {
                 publicMap.set(name.substring(0, name.length-3), mod)
             }
             
        })
```

```
import { Result, Err, Ok } from 'ts-results';

//^^^^^^^^^^ Cannot use import statement outside a module

import * as Handler from "../../types/index"

export default {
        alias: ["p"],
        type: Handler.CommandType.TEXT,
        delegate : () => {
            return Err("pong")
        }
} as Handler.fdjsMod
```

my tsconfig :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src"

  },
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node16/tsconfig.json"
}
```

```
{
  "name": "cheemsbanker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc && node dist/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.3.1",
    "ts-results": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node16": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

```
src
    │   index.ts
    │   secrets.json
    │
    ├───commands
    │   ├───private
    │   │       ping.ts
    │   │
    │   └───public
    ├───handler
    │   │   index.ts
    │   │
    │   ├───events
    │   │       event.ts
    │   │
    │   ├───fdjs
    │   │       fdjs.ts
    │   │
    │   └───utils
    │           readFile.ts
    │
    └───types
        │   index.ts
        │
        └───handler
                handler.ts
```

Things I have tried :

1. Setting type to module in my package.json

- this only leads to an error saying `exports is not defined in ES module scope`

2. Change dist folder js output to .cjs files

- same error

3. Switch between cjs require() and dynamic import()
   -same error

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: typescript detects whether a file is a module or not by the static import/export statements in a `.ts` file. have you tried adding an empty export statement `export {};` in your `types/index.ts` file?

Comment: @ZouJeff i have.  And there is a slight typo in my question: the error occurs at the import statement for { Err, Ok, Result }. (the ts-results package) My apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved : when i was dynamically importing files from my command folder, i was directing it to my src file instead of dist :

```
export default async function getCommands(type: privOrPub) : Promise<string[]> {
    //src/commands/public
    const publicCommands = join(process.cwd(), "src/commands/public")
    const privateCommands = join(process.cwd(), "src/commands/private")

    return type == 'private' ? readPath(privateCommands) : readPath(publicCommands)
}
```

```
export default async function getCommands(type: privOrPub) : Promise<string[]> {
    //src/commands/public -> dist/commands/public
    const publicCommands = join(process.cwd(), "dist/commands/public")
    const privateCommands = join(process.cwd(), "dist/commands/private")

    return type == 'private' ? readPath(privateCommands) : readPath(publicCommands)
}
```

Thanks for the help, everyone. I didnt expect the error to be so trivial

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these attributes to your tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node16/tsconfig.json"
}
```

I'm not sure if this works for you, but it did for me.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work. Still the same error. I think mine involves dynamically importing files.